# python aggregate monthly data

Tags: python, date

I have a dataset that has monthly values. I would like to consolidate multiple rows into one row. But suppose one middle month is missing, I'd like to be aware of that. So i need some function to check if I am adding up rows where first rows End date is the same as the second row's start date.

```
Input
Start date         End date           Value
1/1/2022           1/31/2022           3
1/31/2022          2/28/2022           4
2/28/2022          3/31/2022           5
```

Output

```
Start date         End date           Value
1/1/2022           3/21/2022           12
```

Thanks,
Yiling

haven't seen a solution elsewhere

Comment: What is the desired result if February is missing?

Comment: This seems like it should be a simple loop. Use `if current_row['Start date'] != previous_row['End date']:` to detect when there's a gap.

Answer (score 1):

@Barmar is right. You have to check if the current start date and the previous end date are different. Use `cumsum` to create groups then `aggregate` your data with the right functions:

```
df['Start date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start date'], dayfirst=False)
df['End date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End date'], dayfirst=False)

grp = df['Start date'].ne(df['End date'].shift()).cumsum()

aggfuncs = {'Start date': 'first', 'End date': 'last', 'Value': 'sum'}
out = df.groupby(grp).agg(aggfuncs).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  Start date   End date  Value
0 2022-01-01 2022-03-31     12
```

Intermediate result:

```
>>> grp
0    1  # group 1
1    1  # same group because the current start date not different
2    1  # than the previous end date so you have to aggregate them
dtype: int64
```